# Getting meta tag attribute with HTML Agility Pack using XPATH

Tags: html, html-agility-pack, xpath

```
META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
TITLE>Microsoft Corporation
META http-equiv="PICS-Label" content="(PICS-1.1 "http://www.rsac.org/ratingsv01.html" l gen true r (n 0 s 0 v 0 l 0))" />
META NAME="KEYWORDS" CONTENT="products; headlines; downloads; news; Web site; what's new; solutions; services; software; contests; corporate news;" />
META NAME="DESCRIPTION" CONTENT="The entry page to Microsoft's Web site. Find software, solutions, answers, support, and Microsoft news." />
META NAME="MS.LOCALE" CONTENT="EN-US" />
META NAME="CATEGORY" CONTENT="home page" />
```

I'd like to know what XPATH I would need to get the value of the Content attribute of the Category meta tag using HTML Agility Pack. (I removed the first < of each line in the html code so it would post).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For a long time HtmlAgilityPack [didn't have the ability to directly query an attribute value](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=1720). You had to loop over the list of meta nodes. Here's one way:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlString);

var list = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//meta"); 
foreach (var node in list)
{
    string content = node.GetAttributeValue("content", "");
}
```

But it looks like there is an [experimental xpath release](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/releases/view/46681) that will let you do that.

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//meta/@content")
```

will return a list of HtmlAttribute objects.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for the quick response Rohit Agarwal (I saw it answered only a few hours after I asked, but haven't been able to test it until today).

I did originally implement your suggestion as follows (it's in vb.net)

`Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString(url)
        Dim doc As New HtmlDocument()
        doc.LoadHtml(result)`

```
    Dim list = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//meta")
    Dim node As Object

    For Each node In list
        Dim metaname As String = node.GetAttributeValue("name", String.Empty)
        If metaname <> String.Empty Then
            If (metaname = "title") Then
                title = node.GetAttributeValue("content", String.Empty)
            //more elseif thens
            End if
        End if
    Next (node)
```

However, I've found that //meta[@name='title'] will give me the same result

`Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString(url)`

Dim doc As New HtmlDocument()
doc.LoadHtml(result)

title = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//meta[@name='title']")(0).GetAttributeValue("content", String.Empty)

Thanks for putting me on the right track=D

Comment: Actually, a slightly better way would be to use 
<code>title = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//meta[@name='title']").GetAttributeValue("content", String.Empty)</code>

Comment: Or better yet would be

title = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//meta[@name='title']/@content")

Comment: The above one title = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//meta[@name='title']/@content").ToString won't work...

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the meta tag to display Title, description and keywords then use

```
 if (metaTags != null)
        {
            foreach (var tag in metaTags)
            {
                if ((tag.Attributes["name"] != null) & (tag.Attributes["content"] != null))
                {
                       Panel divPage = new Panel();                        
                       divPage.InnerHtml = divPage.InnerHtml + "<br /> " +
                        "<b> Page " + tag.Attributes["name"].Value + " </b>: " +
                            tag.Attributes["content"].Value + "<br />";
                }
            }
        }
```

If you want to get the `og:tags` from the link add this code after that

```
            if ((tag.Attributes["property"] != null) & (tag.Attributes["content"] != null))
            {
                if (tag.Attributes["property"].Value == "og:image")
                {
                    img.ImageUrl = tag.Attributes["content"].Value;
                }

            }
```

this is great experience... I like :) this code ever

Answer (score 2):

With no Error Checking:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//meta[@name='description']").Attributes["content"].Value;
```

Of course if the Node is Null, or if the Content Attribute is not present this will create an issue.